# Node event loop blocked when no traffic is coming in

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have some strange event loop behavior where my event loop gets blocked even though nothing is happening. I have an Node (4.4.3) Express (4.1.3) app running on AWS Elastic Bean Stalk. I'm using https://github.com/winstonjs/winston to watch all requests coming in. `The GET / 200` is my health checker.

At about 15:39, the event loop gets blocked, but as you can see, from the requests coming in, the only thing going on is a call to the health checker route, which returns a static route.  The `Blocked` is generated using  https://github.com/tj/node-blocked

```
Sun May 29 2016 15:38:16 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:38:20 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 2ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:38:26 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 2ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:38:30 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:38:36 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:38:40 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:38:46 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:38:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 2ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:38:56 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:00 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Blocked 14 ms
Blocked 82 ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:06 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 2ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:10 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:16 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:20 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:26 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:30 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:36 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 2ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:40 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:46 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 1ms
Sun May 29 2016 15:39:50 GMT+0000 (UTC) - info: GET / 200 2ms
```

I'm also running `--trace_gc` and am pretty sure it is not due to a garbage collection. I am using several node_modules, https://gist.github.com/foobar8675/00a63b9c67cc18e30a58968742aba40d, but nothing really out of the ordinary, (that I know of) If anyone has any thoughts, it is much appreciated.

Comment: So, you're asking about the 14ms and 82ms "blocks"?  Looking at how node-block works, it appears to rely on the timing of `setInterval()` so anything that momentarily delays a `setInterval()` getting called exactly when it was scheduled will trigger this notification.

Comment: thanks jfriend00. any suggestions on how to try to figure out what might be causing that momentary delay?

Comment: It's a pretty short duration (the first one only 14ms) so it could be lots of things.  Anything else going on with that computer that occasionally uses the CPU?  Keep in mind that there are lots of OS services on the computer that may occasionally wake up to do something.  You are also running winston that may occasionally have something to do inside of node.js.  How many CPUs in this computer?  What's the RAM usage of node.js  and of the whole system?  I think there are also some aspects of garbage collection that accumulate and then run in a batch that could occasionally lead to a delay.

Comment: Hmmm, now that you mention it, you're on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  You don't control your environment.  You are likely sharing compute resources with other things such that when you aren't utilizing the CPU, the environment can use it for other things.  This may cause a short delay occasionally when your process wants to get running again.

Comment: On a complete side note; In your `package.json` you are compressing your node-modules twice upon deployment. Your deploy builds and compresses :`"deploy": "npm run build && npm run compress && eb deploy"` But youre build compresses as well: `"build": "npm prune --production &&  npm run compress",` Is this intended behaviour or a simple mistake?

Comment: hi jfriend00, it is running on a t2 micro, so 1 core. i have gone through the eb-activity logs looking for something, but can not find anything. I can go with your assumption that there is something else going on that isn't logged.

Comment: hi @LarsdeBruijn, thanks for pointing that out. yes, that is a goof :) lately for deploying, i just use `eb deploy` and not the npm run deploy